# Inserting jquery mobile listview does not format correctly

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile

When I add a jquery mobile listview like this:

```
<ul data-role="listview">
  <li><a href="">test</a></li>
</ul>
```

everything is correctly formatted and looks like it should.

But when I add the exact same thing dynamically with the following javascript code:

```
$('#main [data-role="main"]').append('<ul data-role="listview"><li><a href="#">test</a></li></ul>');
```

it does suddenly not work anymore, meaning there is shown a normal list instead of a listview. How is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you append a listview dynamically, you'll need to call the refresh() method on it to update the styles.

```
$('#main [data-role="main"]').append('<ul data-role="listview"><li><a href="#">test</a></li></ul>');
$("ul").listview( "refresh" );
$("ul").trigger("create");
```

Comment: .trigger("create") inject your HTML into the page.